# Binding to ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth returns 0

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, grid, actualwidth

Paste this into Cider.

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ColumnDefinition}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, run it. The second `TextBlock` shows 0, but shouldn't, right? Workaround?

Answer (score 7):

No, you didn't. ColumnDefinition does have an `ActualWidth` property, actually. But it's neither `DependencyProperty` nor there `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. So nobody let your target know when `ActualWidth` is updated.

Workaround? For what? You can always use `ElementName` binding to the parent `FrameworkElement`, who has exactly that `ActualWidth` that you wanted. Sorry for complex phrase :). Couldn't make it simpler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, I'm trying to use that in a bigger grid with several columns. This is just a demonstration.

Answer (score 4):

The `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` property is not a dependency property and you binding will only show it's initial value which is 0 before the grid has been updated for layout. The `Grid.ActualWidth` property on the other hand is a dependency property and the binding will get updated as the width changes.

Comment: Agreed. It worked when I gave the ColumnDefinition a name and sub-UserControl a name and then assigned in the Loaded event "subUserControl.ParentColumnWidth = colDefName.ActualWidth;"

Answer (score 2):

From [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth.aspx):

> When you add or remove rows or columns, the ActualWidth for all ColumnDefinition elements and the ActualHeight of all RowDefinition elements becomes zero until Measure is called.

It would seem that the value is being bound before `Measure` is being called, somehow. Try forcing `Mode = OneWay` on your binding, and checking manually in code as well, to confirm this behaviour.

Comment: Umm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth.aspx