# Do we have to automatically widen the combo to the selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Thanks to this excellent [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes) I am making good progress with **binding** a `ComboBox`.

But I have an issue and I do not know if this can be resolved with WPF.

Here is the class:

```
namespace OCLMEditor
{
    /// This class provides us with an object to fill a ComboBox with
    /// that can be bound to string fields in the binding object.
    public class ComboBoxItemString
    {
        public string ValueString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my App.XAML file I have the following resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="SongTitleString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Title 1"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Title 2"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "&quot;Title 3&quot;"/>
    </x:Array>
</Application.Resources>
```

There are 154 items in that array. When I run the application and select an item from the list this is what happens.

**Before**:

[image: Selecting a longer droplist item]

As you can see, the combo list is wider than the actual combo box. But I am fine with that. But when you select the item, **afterwards** it looks like:

[image: After]

The combo is declared like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitleString}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="ValueString" 
    SelectedValuePath="ValueString" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SongTitleString}" />
```

I don't want it to be editable. So is there any way that, when we select a entry from the combo, it does not widen the actual combo itself? If it is possible, (so it shows clipped text)?

It also happens when I am using a editable combo. Example:

[image: Update]

Extra markup info:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,10,5" Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <Grid Height="auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Label>Week of Meeting:</Label>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                            <Image Source="special_event.png"></Image>
                            <Label>Date 1</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                            <Image Source="special_event.png"></Image>
                            <Label>Date 2</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                            <Image Source="special_event.png"></Image>
                            <Label>Date 3</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="event_time.png" Margin="2"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <Label>Note:</Label>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{StaticResource NoteString}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="ValueString" 
                SelectedValuePath="ValueString" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding Note}" />                    
            <Label>Bible Reading for Week:</Label>
            <TextBox>PSALMS 60-68</TextBox>
            <Label>Opening Song:</Label>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitleString}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="ValueString" 
                SelectedValuePath="ValueString" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding SongTitle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <Label>Chairman:</Label>
            <ComboBox></ComboBox>
            <Label>Auxiliary Counsellor 1:</Label>
            <ComboBox></ComboBox>
            <Label>Auxiliary Counsellor 2:</Label>
            <ComboBox></ComboBox>
            <Label>Prayer:</Label>
            <ComboBox></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

This link: [WPF how to make Grid Reevaluate Max Widths on GridSplitter Column Resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416949/wpf-how-to-make-grid-reevaluate-max-widths-on-gridsplitter-column-resize)

Has an answer:

> MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=SignalValuesGridSplitter,Path=ActualWidth}"
>   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

So I might be able to follow that idea but can't work it out.

Thank you.

Resized:

[image: Resized]

Update to accepted answer:

```
<ComboBox.MaxWidth>
    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
        ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
</ComboBox.MaxWidth>
```

Comment: That is odd.  It would help if you could reproduce with a much simpler example.  No one is going to try and reproduce that.  I would look at ItemTemplate for the combox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably not exactly what are looking for but should put you on the right path

```
   <GridBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </GridBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And then try binding the Width of the TextBlock to another valid width from and element

Width="Stretch" may work

Comment: Thank you. Got it working by using my textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `MaxWidth`on the ComboBox. Without knowing the rest of the markup you could put your controls in a `Grid`. That will allow you to set the `ColumnWidth` so that the other controls that i see in the screen shot will have the same width.

Comment: Thank you. I have already put it in a grid. I have updated the question with my markup, incase it helps.

Comment: You can set the ColumnDefinition to "*' for both columns. This will give each column the same size.

Comment: I have changed it to use the 1* for each. It does look better. But I can't set the `MaxWidth` because my columns resize. So the value is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like setting a `MaximumWidth` on your ComboBox would be preferable here.

`comboBox.MaxWidth = 150;`  < or, whatever value fits your case of course.

Information is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxwidth(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it is conflicting with the markup. The control is stretchable you see. So the MaxWidth value needs to be changed as the width of the containers change. I added the markup to the question. Can we cater for that?

Comment: I tried overiding the  grids resize event and then setting the maxwidth property, but it didn't work. I think because it was set the once, it never resizes again.

Comment: I see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416949/wpf-how-to-make-grid-reevaluate-max-widths-on-gridsplitter-column-resize

Comment: You should also be able to have the size itself set to Auto and the MaxWidth set to a different value. You still want it to change size just not beyond a certain point right?

Comment: The combo changes width as the grip is dragged. But the MaxWidth property should always be consistent with the current width of the combo.

Comment: That question I  put a link to implies using binding. But i can't work out how to do that.

Comment: You mean when the window is resized the combobox changes sizes as well? You can disallow resizing of the window as well, although MaxWidth should still stop it from going beyond that value

Comment: Updated question. Yes when I use the gripper then the combobox changes size too. This is what I want. But this MaxWidth property has to be teh same as the active size of the combo.

Comment: In that case it is quite confusing what you are trying to accomplish. The MaxWidth property really should only be set once, as that is the largest value that property will allow after initialization. I think what you mean is you want to **resize the combobox with the text size of the selected item, but only up to a certain extent**. Is this right?